# Как подключить к Visual Studio 2017 ODB, работающий с SQLite

Tags: c++, sqlite, visual-studio-2017, orm, sqlite3

Одна программа, включающая хэдер с классами и его cpp с методами, генерирует данные. Необходимо эти данные сохранять в БД. А потом другая программа их будет оттуда забирать или как-то обрабатывать. Краткий обзор возможностей просто Sqlite3 и ORM ODB привел к выводу, что ODB продуктивнее и удобнее, так как можно записывать в БД классы целиком и не заморачиваться. Но есть сложность - как же включить библиотеки libodb-2.4.0 и libodb-sqlite-2.4.0 в проект Visual Studio 2017? К тому же необходимо добавить компилятор odb, т.к. часть файлов он предварительно обрабатывает. А так же реализовать в Visual Studio 2017 поэтапную сборку, аналогичную строкам G++:

```
odb -d sqlite --generate-query --generate-schema person.hxx
g++ -c driver.cxx
g++ -c person-odb.cxx
g++ -o driver driver.o person-odb.o -lodb-sqlite -lodb
```

Не получилось решить задачу, используя MINGW64. Ищу другие пути, надеюсь Visual Studio 2017 упростит задачу.

Comment: Что значит "Не получилось"? Чем сборка в VS вам что-то упростит?

Comment: Даже простейший пример из мануала имеет итогом ошибку undefined reference to ...Которая никак не решается... Значит что-то не так в сборке библиотеки. А при сборке всё время вылезают ошибки, да и при компиляции этих простейших 4-х строк добавлено куча -I и -L. Хочется уже от этого уйти к автоматической сборке, а не ручной.

Comment: Автоматическая сборка предполагает написание все той же кучи -l -L и прочих аргументов (обычно *каждая* команда для сборки занимает по несколько строк). Если вы не разобрались с нужными аргументами, то переход на VS (точнее на msbuild) вам ничем не поможет. VS не умеет угадывать и автоматически выставлять нужные параметры сборки. Если вы получаете ошибки, то их надо приводить в самом вопросе.

Comment: Привожу ссылку на вопрос про ошибки https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/959609/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-odb-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81-sqlite

Comment: Это руководство пробовали: https://www.codesynthesis.com/products/odb/doc/install-windows.xhtml ?

Comment: Сборка библиотек по данному ресурсу производилась, в дополнительно скачанном MINGW32(MSYS 1.0), так так используемом MINGW64 при сборке libodb-2-4.dll ругался на отсутствие знаков препинания в Makefile для сборки, а потом ещё на флаги ругался при сборке libodb-sqlite-2-4 и не собирал...
При установке на другой комп ./configure не нашел gcc...cc... и не стал выполнять команду, хотя я работаю там из MINGW64 - как нет gcc???

Comment: Все просто, в VS в события сборки надо включить `odb -d sqlite --generate-query ...` в PreBuild Event, остальное оно соберёт само, результаты исполнения этой команды, надо включить руками в проект.

Comment: “Надо включать руками в проект»-плавали, знаем. Мне пришлось изобрести грязный хак, чтобы прямо из build event патчить файл проекта