# Не компилируется простейший пример из мануала по ODB при работе с sqlite

Tags: c++, sqlite, orm, sqlite3, g++

Пытаюсь собрать пример из мануала по odb (https://www.codesynthesis.com/products/odb/doc/manual.xhtml#7.2). Необходимо данные класса сохранить в db sqlite. Ошибка компилятора G++ при линковке:

```
    $ g++ -L c:/tools/odb/mingw -L c:/work/study/libs -L c:/work/study/libodb-2.4.0/odb/.libs -L c:/work/study/libodb-sqlite-2.4.0/odb/sqlite/.libs -o driver driver.o person-odb.o -lodb-sqlite -lodb
driver.o:driver.cxx:(.text+0x177): undefined reference to `person::person(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, unsigned short)'
driver.o:driver.cxx:(.text+0x234): undefined reference to `person::person(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, unsigned short)'
driver.o:driver.cxx:(.text+0x2f1): undefined reference to `person::person(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, unsigned short)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Сам makefile выглядит так:

```
odb -d sqlite --generate-query --generate-schema person.hxx                        
g++ -I c:/work/study/libodb-2.4.0 -I c:/work/study/libodb-sqlite-2.4.0 -I c:/work/study/include --std c++98 -c driver.cxx                                                
g++ -I c:/work/study/libodb-2.4.0 -I c:/work/study/libodb-sqlite-2.4.0 -I c:/work/study/include --std c++98 -c person-odb.cxx                                            
g++ -L c:/tools/odb/mingw/lib -L c:/work/study/libs -L c:/work/study/libodb-2.4.0/odb/.libs -L c:/work/study/libodb-sqlite-2.4.0/odb/sqlite/.libs -o driver driver.o person-odb.o -lodb-sqlite -lodb
```

Файлы проекта:

```
// driver.cxx
//

#include <memory>   // std::auto_ptr
#include <iostream>

#include <odb/database.hxx>
#include <odb/transaction.hxx>

#include <odb/sqlite/database.hxx>

#include "person.hxx"
#include "person-odb.hxx"

using namespace std;
using namespace odb::core;

int
main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    auto_ptr<database> db (new odb::sqlite::database (argc, argv));

    unsigned long john_id, jane_id, joe_id;

    // Create a few persistent person objects.
    //
    {
      person john ("John", "Doe", 33);
      person jane ("Jane", "Doe", 32);
      person joe ("Joe", "Dirt", 30);

      transaction t (db->begin ());

      // Make objects persistent and save their ids for later use.
      //
      john_id = db->persist (john);
      jane_id = db->persist (jane);
      joe_id = db->persist (joe);

      t.commit ();
    }
  }
  catch (const odb::exception& e)
  {
    cerr << e.what () << endl;
    return 1;
  }
}

// person.hxx
//
#ifndef SOURCE_HPP
#define SOURCE_HPP

#include <string>

#include <odb/core.hxx>     // (1)

#pragma db object           // (2)
class person
{
public:  
  person(std::string firstName, std::string lastName, unsigned short age);
  //const std::string& email () const;
  //void email (const std::string&);

 /*  const std::string& get_name () const;
  std::string& set_name ();

  unsigned short getAge () const;
  void setAge (unsigned short); */

private:
  person () {}              // (3)

  friend class odb::access; // (4)

  #pragma db id auto        // (5)
  unsigned long id_;        // (5)

  std::string first_;
  std::string last_;
  unsigned short age_;
};

#endif // SOURCE_HPP

// person.cxx
//

#include <string>

#include "person.hxx"    

  //const std::string& get_name () const;
  //std::string& set_name ();

  //unsigned short getAge () const;
  //void setAge (unsigned short);

person::person(std::string firstName, std::string lastName, unsigned short age)
{
    first_ = firstName;
    last_ = lastName;
    age_ = age;
}
```

Подскажите, что не так? Почему такие ошибки? Как исправить?

Comment: Согласно мануалу --generate-schema должен генерировать person.sql, а этого почему-то не происходит...

Comment: [тыц](https://www.codesynthesis.com/pipermail/odb-users/2015-July/002659.html)

Comment: Спасибо, доходчиво!!!)